# Issues with WebSphere MQ + Transactions

Tags: c#, .net, transactions, ibm-mq

I'm having some issues with webSphere - I am trying to run the SimpleXAGet client which basically just transactionally reads from a queue. I have a Queue on a QM running on another server and when I try to read from it, I see a connection gets open to it - but I always get an error : "CompCode: 2, Reason: 2085".

If I remove the code for the TransactionScope and no longer do them in a transaction, reads and writes work fine.

Not sure whats wrong, anyone familiar enough to take a couple guesses?

Comment: No, only running a single QM with a single queue running on it. Works fine if I don't try to read transactionally.

Comment: No, only one instance of the QueueManager running. Again, it seems to work fine if my code doesn't wrap a transactionscope around the MQGet. I'm not sure how to check that SYSTEM.ADMIN.QMGR.EVENT queue, I don't see it anywhere. Its just so strange, everything works fine as long as I don't use the SyncPoint option - but without it, the transaction logic doesn't work.

Comment: In addition, when I am calling into the Get method, after the MQ Exception is thrown with the 2085 error, I can see on my QM the connection is open to my client application. It just can't seem to read or write to the queue (unless I take it out of the transaction scope)

Comment: Is there anything special I need to do on the queue manager to create a transactional queue?

Comment: Can you check to see if your queue manager has a `SYSTEM.DOTNET.XARECOVERY.QUEUE` queue?  This is required for .NET XA transactions.  I was able to reproduce the 2085 error by deleting this queue on a test queue manager.  If this is it I'll write up a answer for you to accept.

Comment: Thanks for your help with this, it is much appreciated.... Where would this queue be found on my queue manager? The only queues I see are the ones Ive created myself. I dont see any such queue...

Comment: Ah, okay. I didn't see the option in my explorer to show system objects. I do not see that queue in my list of system queues.

Comment: Wow, adding that queue resolved my issue. I can't thank you enough. Please feel free to type up an answer and I will accept it. Thanks again, your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: QM Version is 7.0

Comment: Do you know what the specific version of MQ the Qmgr is? ex: 7.0.1.14?  If you create a fresh queue manager as a test does this object exist?  If it does then likely it was removed at some point.  The proper method to restore it as MQ intended is to use stop MQ and `strmqm -c QMGRNAME`, but note this will also override all the settings on the `SYSTEM.*` queues to the original default values, so if for example you changed a setting of `SYSTEM.DEFAULT.LOCAL.QUEUE` like `MAXDEPTH(10000)`, any new queue would have that value but after running the `strmqm -c` it would go back to `MAXDEPTH(5000)`.

Comment: This queue was NOT removed. But the QM is a trial version only good for like 30 or 60 days. Not sure if thats why it wasn't installed.

Comment: Version in the read me says  7.0.1.0

Comment: Note that MQ v7.0.x.x has been out of support since September 2015, 7.1.x.x went of support April 2017, and 7.5 went out of support April 2018.  You can download a fully functional [IBM MQ Advances for Developers](https://developer.ibm.com/messaging/mq-downloads/) to setup queue managers to test with and these have currently supported versions of MQ (8.0, 9.0, and 9.1).

Comment: Thank you for all your help. Seriously, this was an issue that needed a quick resolution and I would have never known about that missing queue without your help. Many thanks.

Comment: Also note that unless you actually use the `WmqDotnetXAMonitor.exe` that comes with the MQ Client, you can't resolve XA transactions.  Are you trying to use .NET too coordinate a transaction that involves MQ and something else? If not then you can simply use normal PUT and GET under SYNCPOINT with out XA and then that queue would not come into play.