# IBM MQ Put inside .NET TransactionScope throws MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED

Tags: .net, .net-core, ibm-mq, msdtc

Any idea why the following minimal example throws MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED MQException with the following command line output?

```
Connecting to queue manager.. done
Accessing queue DEV.QUEUE.1.. done
Message .. 
MQException caught: 2035 - MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED
   at IBM.WMQ.MQDestination.Put(MQMessage message, MQPutMessageOptions pmo)
   at IBMMQTests.WMQTests.PutInsideTransactionScope() in WMQTests.cs:line 40
```

The example is adapted from IBM MQ .NET sample `SimpleXAPut.cs` (cf. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q029320_.html), and run with IBM MQ running as a container on localhost:

```
docker run --env LICENSE=accept --env MQ_QMGR_NAME=QM1 --publish 1414:1414 --publish 9443:9443 ibmcom/mq
```

This happens on both macOS (.NET Core) and on Windows (both .NET Core and .NET Framework) - using the IBM MQ .NET Standard client NuGet package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/IBMMQDotnetClient/

The transaction scope is necessary for coordinating transactions across multiple systems (i.e., database and message queue).

```cs
using System;
using System.Transactions;
using IBM.WMQ;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace IBMMQTests
{
    public class WMQTests
    {
        [Test]
        public void PutInsideTransactionScope()
        {
            var connectionName = "localhost";
            var queueManagerName = "QM1";
            var channelName = "DEV.APP.SVRCONN";
            var queueName = "DEV.QUEUE.1";
            try
            {
                using (var transactionScope = new TransactionScope())
                {
                    Console.Write("Connecting to queue manager.. ");
                    var queueManager = new MQQueueManager(queueManagerName, channelName, connectionName);
                    Console.WriteLine("done");
                    Console.Write("Accessing queue " + queueName + ".. ");
                    var queue = queueManager.AccessQueue(queueName, MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING);
                    Console.WriteLine("done");

                    //create putMessageOptions object
                    var putMessageOptions = new MQPutMessageOptions
                    {
                        Options = MQC.MQPMO_SYNCPOINT
                    };

                    // creating a message
                    var message = new MQMessage();
                    message.WriteString("TestMessage");

                    Console.Write("Message .. ");
                    queue.Put(message, putMessageOptions);
                    Console.WriteLine("put");

                    Console.Write("Transaction ending.. ");
                    // commits the transaction
                    transactionScope.Complete();
                    Console.WriteLine("committed");

                    Console.Write("Closing queue " + queueName + ".. ");
                    queue.Close();
                    Console.WriteLine("done");

                    Console.Write("Disconnecting queue manager.. ");
                    queueManager.Disconnect();
                    Console.WriteLine("done");
                }
            }
            catch (MQException mqe)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("MQException caught: {0} - {1}", mqe.ReasonCode, mqe.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(mqe.StackTrace);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check what error shows up in the queue manager's AMQERR01.LOG file, this will tell you the cause of the MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED.

Comment: I think you are probably getting a permission error on ` SYSTEM.DOTNET.XARECOVERY.QUEUE`.

Comment: Check the MQ docker container version - 9.1.5 and above should be ok, whereby if you don't provide an app password then `DEV.APP.SVRCONN` is not secured. `docker image inspect <your image id> --format '{{.ContainerConfig.Labels.version}}'`

Comment: @chughts the question shows it got past the connection to the queue manager and even opened the queue.   It only failed on the the put.

Comment: Good point. As a transaction is involved the unauthorised is likely to be related to missing permissions on a transaction related component.

Comment: stemann, did you figure out the problem,  if my comment helped I'll write up a quick answer.

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: @JoshMc You were right (output obtained by running the container in interactive mode (`docker run -it --env LICENSE=accept --env MQ_QMGR_NAME=QM1 --publish 1414:1414 --publish 9443:9443 ibmcom/mq`):

AMQ8077W: Entity 'app' has insufficient authority to access object SYSTEM.DOTNET.XARECOVERY.QUEUE [queue]. [CommentInsert1(app), CommentInsert2(SYSTEM.DOTNET.XARECOVERY.QUEUE [queue]), CommentInsert3(get/put)]

Is there any way to get the MQ container to authorize access to `SYSTEM.DOTNET.XARECOVERY.QUEUE`?

Comment: @chughts Image tag: ibm-mqadvanced-server-dev:9.2.0.0-r2-amd64

Comment: @JoshMc I guess we also need to run the `WmqDotnetXAMonitor.exe` that comes with the MQ Client, as you mentioned a while ago? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52995530/issues-with-websphere-mq-transactions#comment92934424_52995530 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61888890/ibm-mq-transactions-and-net#comment109464748_61888890