# IBM MQ Put inside .NET TransactionScope throws MQRC_UOW_ENLISTMENT_ERROR

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, ibm-mq

This is a continuation of [IBM MQ Put inside .NET TransactionScope throws MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66389927/ibm-mq-put-inside-net-transactionscope-throws-mqrc-not-authorized), but I lack the necessary reputation to comment on that question. I've got past the error in the aforementioned post (MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED) and am now getting the following instead:

```
Connecting to queue manager.. done
Accessing queue DEV.QUEUE.1.. done
Message .. 
MQException caught: 2354 - MQRC_UOW_ENLISTMENT_ERROR
   at IBM.WMQ.MQDestination.Put(MQMessage message, MQPutMessageOptions pmo)
   at MQTest.WMQTests.Main(String[] args) in /Users/nlc/Projects/MQTest/MQTest/Program.cs:line 38
```

Here is a link to a description of the error by IBM https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.tro.doc/q043830_.htm.

My example is adapted from the aforementioned post and is run with IBM MQ running as a container on localhost:

```
docker run --env LICENSE=accept --env MQ_QMGR_NAME=QM1 --publish 1414:1414 --publish 9443:9443 --detach ibmcom/mq:lates
```

So far I've tried on macOS (.NET Core), using the IBM MQ .NET Standard client NuGet package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/IBMMQDotnetClient/

Note that if I drop the `putMessageOptions` in my `Put()` call on line 38 or drop the transaction scope, it succeeds.

This is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Transactions;
using IBM.WMQ;

namespace MQTest
{
    public class WMQTests
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var connectionName = "localhost";
            var queueManagerName = "QM1";
            var channelName = "DEV.APP.SVRCONN";
            var queueName = "DEV.QUEUE.1";

            try
            {
                using (var transactionScope = new TransactionScope())
                {
                    Console.Write("Connecting to queue manager.. ");
                    var queueManager = new MQQueueManager(queueManagerName, channelName, connectionName);
                    Console.WriteLine("done");
                    Console.Write("Accessing queue " + queueName + ".. ");
                    var queue = queueManager.AccessQueue(queueName, MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING);
                    Console.WriteLine("done");

                    //create putMessageOptions object
                    var putMessageOptions = new MQPutMessageOptions
                    {
                        Options = MQC.MQPMO_SYNCPOINT
                    };

                    // creating a message
                    var message = new MQMessage();
                    message.WriteString("TestMessage");

                    Console.Write("Message .. ");
                    queue.Put(message, putMessageOptions);
                    Console.WriteLine("put");

                    Console.Write("Transaction ending.. ");
                    // commits the transaction
                    transactionScope.Complete();
                    Console.WriteLine("committed");

                    Console.Write("Closing queue " + queueName + ".. ");
                    queue.Close();
                    Console.WriteLine("done");

                    Console.Write("Disconnecting queue manager.. ");
                    queueManager.Disconnect();
                    Console.WriteLine("done");
                }
            }
            catch (MQException mqe)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("MQException caught: {0} - {1}", mqe.ReasonCode, mqe.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(mqe.StackTrace);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Distributed transactions are not supported with MQ .NET Standard libraries and i think MS itself doesn't support Distributed Transactions with .NET Core application

Comment: See [Installing IBM MQ classes for .NET Standard](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.2.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q132490_.html#q132490_), Table 1 shows Distributed transactions are Not supported with IBM MQ classes for .NET Standard. @subbaraoc IBM should return a more meaningful error than `MQRC_UOW_ENLISTMENT_ERROR` or at least update the 9.2 version of the KC page the OP linked to about the error to cover this IBM MQ classes for .NET Standard cause.

Comment: @liljedahl You can also achieve this using .NET Framework application and using amqmdnet.dll

Comment: @JoshMc okay sure will make a note of it